# Adding and removing from a search query with a button click

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, wordpress

I have set up a filter on a search results page to enable the user to narrow down their results by the type of hotel they are looking for. The only problem is that it just adds to the search string so the more hotel types they click the longer the query gets and also if the unclick a term it remains in the url. What I ideally need to do is this:

On button click:

- Add query to url if not already present.
- If search criteria is already in the url remove it.

```
<a class="category_buttons" id="cat_2" onclick="javascript:window.location.search += '&tax_category=2'">
    <img src="/wp-content/uploads/2017/09/bb-icons-trees2.png" />
    <span>Country Retreat</span>
</a>
```

Comment: @parthpatel: thanks for wanting to improve this post. However, you misunderstood the sentence structure here, and made it less readable. Please don't edit posts if you are not confident with English grammar, as it necessitates repair work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var hash;
var item = {};
    

function searchParameter(key, value){

    var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') + 1).split('&');
        
    for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
    {
        hash = hashes[i].split('=');
        if(hash[1]!==undefined)
            item[hash[0]] = hash[1];
    }

    var idx = (key in item);
    if (!idx || item[key]!=value) {
        item[key] =  value;
    } else {
        delete item[key];
    }
    var url = window.location.href.split("?")[0];
   window.location.href = url+"?"+$.param(item);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="searchParameter('tax_category',2)" class='t'>Category 2</a>

<a href='javascript:void(0)' onclick="searchParameter('tax_category',3)" class='t'>Category 3</a>

<a href='javascript:void(0)'  onclick="searchParameter('tax_brand',3)" class='t'>Brand</a>


<a href='javascript:void(0)'  onclick="searchParameter('size','xl')" class='t'>Size</a>
```

above code will make JSON object on button click, if an item is not there in the object then it will add the item else delete the item from the object and `$.param` will convert JSON object to URL query string please check in the console, remove comment from window.location.search in order to get functionality

Comment: I can't seem to get that to work. It deletes the rest of the query and just adds the new query to the end.

Comment: you need to get the base url then append this after that